# Using Slider on LiveCard

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Is there a way to use a Slider on a Livecard ? I've been using them on Activities, but on Livecards I just need to publish a RemoteView on the timeline, so there is no Activity to pass to the Slider.

Comment: Can you qualify the question more? Are you asking how to put an intractable slider on a LiveCard?

Comment: It would be the same use case as one would expect on an Activity. Just a indeterminate slider that shows while data is getting loaded

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Sliders will need a view for the `Slider.from(View v)` call.